# Problems with Azure REST API and high volume

Tags: performance, azure, rest, entity-framework-core

The task is to return 100K rows in a single REST API call.  This is hierarchical data that will be described in a class model in the api.  It is retrieved from SQL Server using Entity Framework, then moved from entity to model using Automapper.  The model gets serialized to json to get passed to the consumer.  When this is called from a front-end application it takes several minutes (the app may be taking time displaying the data) .   If I run the query in SSMS it takes about 7 seconds.   What is wrong with this picture?   I'm thinking this must be a bad conceptual design.   Are there any tips about passing a high volume of data in a REST API?

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider implementing paging. Odds are the rendering of the data on the client is the bottle neck.
2. Ensure you are eager loading dependent entities.
3. Ensure you have change tracking disables for the fetch.
4. Test each part of the chain for performance. use the stopwatch to time the ToListAsync call and log it. then the automapper function call. next write a test console app to use HttpClient to just execute the Rest Call.

Can you show us your controller class?
Can you show us your entities?
Can you show us your repository class (if you are using one)?
Can you show us your DbContext